# Displaying data from mysql into two bootstrap columns using php

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to display info from a mysql database into two bootstrap columns. One product per md-5 column.( ). What i got so far (quite a noob in web dev).

```
 <?php 
    require "conexion.php";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos" ;
    $resultado  = mysqli_query($laConexion,$sql);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap 3, from LayoutIt!</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Source code generated using layoutit.com">
    <meta name="author" content="LayoutIt!">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
        <?php while($fila){ ?>
        <p><?phpecho $fila["Nombre"];?></p>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
        <?php while($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){ ?>
        <p><?php echo $fila2["Nombre"]; ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What im trying to do is a 3 column page (2-5-5) where in the 2 5s columns display data from a DB in order, spliting the data in those two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the loop in the correct way, you need to loop each row as follow

```
<?php while($fila){ ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
        <p><?phpecho $fila["Nombre"];?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
        <p><?php echo $fila["Nombre"]; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This should buil the colums as requested and populate them according

As op requested

```
$i=1;
<?php while($fila){ ?>
    <?php if ($i % 2 != 0){ ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
            <p><?php echo $fila["Nombre"];?></p>
            </div>
    <?php } else { ?> 

            <div class="col-md-5">
            <p><?php echo $fila["Nombre"]; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    $i++;
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is because you used `$fila["Nombre"]` in both columns, change one with another column name that suits your needs

Comment: but i want to populate both with $fila["Nombre"], one on each side. Exmpl. Coke (1st column) - Sprite (2nd column)  but what i am getting is Coke(1st column) Sprite(1st column) - Coke(2nd column) Sprite(2nd column).